# $\lim_{x \to 2, y\to 1}\frac{\sin^{-1}(xy-2)}{\tan^{-1}(3xy-6)}$

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x \to 2, y\to 1}\frac{\sin^{-1}(xy-2)}{\tan^{-1}(3xy-6)}$$
Since the numerator and denominator both go to $0$ when $(x,y) \to (2,1)$, for one variable case we can use L'Hopitals rule, but for two variables case, I do not know how to calculate it.

I also tried to use the definition, means wrote as 
$$\lim_{h \to 0, k\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin^{-1}[(x+h)(y+k)-2]}{\tan^{-1}[3(x+h)(y+k)-6]}-\frac{\sin^{-1}(xy-2)}{\tan^{-1}(3xy-6)}}{?}$$
But still do not know how to do further...Any help? Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ only appear as a product, and $xy\to2$ as $x\to2$ and $y\to1$, it's equivalent to compute the limit

$$\lim_{t\to2}\frac{\sin^{-1}(t-2)}{\tan^{-1}(3t-6)}$$

The numerator and denominator tend to zero, and they are differentiable, so we can apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). The derivatives are respectively $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(t-2)^2}}$ and $\dfrac{3}{1+(3t-6)^2}$, and they both have a nonzero limit as $t\to2$, hence

$$\lim_{t\to2}\frac{\sin^{-1}(t-2)}{\tan^{-1}(3t-6)}=\lim_{t\to2}\frac{1+(3t-6)^2}{3\sqrt{1-(t-2)^2}}=\frac13$$